# Looking for a pattern for working with serial communication

Tags: android, kotlin, serial-port, uart

I am developing an Android application where I must send and receive data over a serial link, an UART to be precise.

My UART handling class is centered around this function:

```
fun receive(expectedLength: Int, timeout: Int): ByteArray {
    // println("Should receive $expectedLength bytes within $timeout ms")
    var read_bytes = 0
    var ret: Int
    var readBuffer: ByteArray = byteArrayOf()
    var start_millis: Long
    start_millis = System.currentTimeMillis()

    while (read_bytes < expectedLength && (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_millis < timeout) ) {
        if (uart.inputStream.available() == 0) {
            ret = -1
            Thread.sleep(10)
        } else {
            ret = uart.inputStream.read()
        }

        if (ret >= 0 ) {
            readBuffer = readBuffer.plus(ret.toByte())
            read_bytes++
            start_millis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    }
    return readBuffer
} // receive expected length with timeout
```

In real life there are several issues with this function, like for instance a "message" can be shorter or longer than the `expectedLength` (perhaps I'm waiting for an acknowledgement/confirmation worth of 10 bytes but receive an error of 6 bytes, or even worse, the other way around) or may take slightly longer to arrive.

All this translates into a cascade of errors throughout the application where various services can only chalk this up under communication/hardware errors. Not even retrying is safe.

Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: I'm not sure based on reading your prior question and this one how you have configured communicating with the UART (USB, direct hardware) and if this implementation exists on a Custom/OEM ROM or not.

Comment: I am looking for a more general solution to handle incoming data from a serial port, rather than something that applies to my particular setup.

Comment: How is Android connecting to serial port? Consumer devices only have USB. And processing UART buffers at the app layer seems will get your result. If using consumer/stock hardware, I would look at [Connecting CDC device to Android over USB-C, with concurrent charging. A cheap option?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/511295/5078). Note that for the now dead [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/versions/things-1.0#peripheral_io) they provided a custom API.

Comment: Some (non-consumer) devices have serial connections, or perhaps emulating one over USB, shouldn't matter. We're talking what's happening beyond the point of acquiring input and output streams.

Comment: If they have serial connectors, they have an OEM SDK. If not, check if they support [Android Open Accessory protocol](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol), or if you are using an existing library like: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android state which one.

Comment: Looks like that library has a read() function that works based on a similar timeout-based strategy, it doesn't support exiting immediately if the expected buffer size has been reached. I need something that works without all that. Probably should switch to i2c...